# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DataLibrary.PLANT>'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join, linq-to-entities

I have worked on trying to get this first attempt at a JOIN with the EntityFramework LINQ query.  When I create this query without the join, I don't get the error.  What do I need to do?

```
public List<PLANT> getPlantDetails(int plantid)
{
    List<PLANT> plantDetails = (from plant in db.PLANTs
                                join bloom in db.BLOOMs on plant.PLANT_ID equals bloom.PLANT_ID
                                where plant.PLANT_ID == bloom.PLANT_ID
                                && plant.PLANT_ID == plantid
                                select new
                                {
                                    plant.PLANT_ID,
                                    plant.PL_GENUS,
                                    plant.PL_SPECIES,
                                    plant.PL_NAME,
                                    plant.PL_DESC,
                                    plant.PL_HEIGHT,
                                    plant.PL_SPACING,
                                    plant.PL_IMAGE,
                                    plant.PL_IMAGE_THUMB,
                                    bloom.BLOOM_DESC
                                }).ToList();

    return plantDetails;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are selecting a new anonymous type. Instead, select  new PLANT object

```
select new PLANT
 {
    //set values here

 }).ToList();
```

edit* just noticing you want to bring in a value from BLOOMs - in that case you can maybe create a new non-mapped property to the PLANT class for bloom desc or you can create a new class which holds BLOOM and PLANT properties and then select that instead.

Comment: I get the error:  Cannot initialize type 'DataLibrary.PLANT' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'Systems.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: Make sure you are using Object Initialization when selecting the new PLANT object
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx